# vector in the upper argument in the integrate function in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I want to integrate the below function

```
function(x) (0.01^2.5)*2.5*x^(2.5-1)
```

where I should integrate for varying upper bounds.

```
upper.bound=seq(0,100)
```

normally I will use

```
sapply(upper.bounds, function(t) integrate(function(x) (0.01^2.5)*2.5*x^(2.5-1), lower = 0, upper = t))
```

or

```
for(t in upper.bounds)
integrate(function(x) (0.01^2.5)*2.5*x^(2.5-1), lower=0, upper=t)
```

However, in my program, it takes so much time to compute with more complex function(x) and larger size of "upper.bounds".

Both of the above method are too slow to use in my program, is there anyway to speed up the computation? I wrote the above code in rcpp, where I use rcpp version of numerical integration. But it is still too slow to use.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `integrate` seems to be a wrapper for C code anyways. You need to either parallelize your loop, use a language with better looping speed, or if possible calculated closed form integral solutions (It would be a waste of time to numerically integrate your example function for example)

Comment: It seems I cannot calculate the closed form in the real function that I have, I am using rcpp for better looping speed. How should I approach to parallelize this loop?

Comment: `doParallel` `foreach` Try Matlab, maybe their whole numerical integration stuff is more optimized.

Comment: Rather than integrate from 0 to UB1, then 0 to UB2, then 0 to UB3, ... with 100 subdivisions each, you should integrate from 0 to UB1, then UB1 to UB2, then UB2 to UB3 with fewer subdivisions. You can then `cumsum` the results. Otherwise you are wasting time re-integrating the same stretches again and again.

Comment: With 100 UB values, you could probably get away with *very* few subdivisions. Fewer subdivisions will lead to fewer function evaluations, which is where you can really save time. It's not that the `integrate` function is slow, all the real time is spent evaluating your function. To get more efficiency, you either need to speed up your function or reduce the number of evaluations.